# Call USSD from background, Retrieve response and further sending request

Tags: java, android, ussd

I am trying to dial ussd number from the background, get the response and parsing the response if it applies, I would like to choose the options. For example if I dial *XYZ# and the response returns with 3 options - A, B, C then I would like to show users these options and if the user lets say, selects B, then I would like to send option B as my selected options. Here's the snippets I am currently stuck at. And it doesn't work. I am using kitkat.

MainActivity.java

```
package io.github.hassannomani.phonecalling;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String ussd = "*141" + Uri.encode("#");
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            //GlobalDefinitions.IsProgramRunning=true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd));
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

  /*          Intent forService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), USSDService.class);
            startService(forService);
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)));*/
        }
    });
}
```

}

USSDService.java

```
package io.github.hassannomani.phonecalling;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;



public class USSDService extends AccessibilityService {
public static String TAG = "alvires";

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent");

    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
/* if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED && !event.getClassName().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")) { // android.app.AlertDialog is the standard but not for all phones  */
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED && !String.valueOf(event.getClassName()).contains("AlertDialog")) {
        return;
    }
    if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED && (source == null || !source.getClassName().equals("android.widget.TextView"))) {
        return;
    }
    if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED && TextUtils.isEmpty(source.getText())) {
        return;
    }

    List<CharSequence> eventText;

    if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
        eventText = event.getText();
    } else {
        eventText = Collections.singletonList(source.getText());
    }

    String text = processUSSDText(eventText);

    if( TextUtils.isEmpty(text) ) return;

    // Close dialog
    performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK); // This works on 4.1+ only

    Log.d(TAG, text);
    // Handle USSD response here

}

private String processUSSDText(List<CharSequence> eventText) {
    for (CharSequence s : eventText) {
        String text = String.valueOf(s);
        // Return text if text is the expected ussd response
        if( true ) {
            return text;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
    info.packageNames = new String[]{"io.github.hassannomani.phonecalling"};
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="io.github.hassannomani.phonecalling">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="io.github.hassannomani.phonecalling.USSDService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@layout/ussd_service" />
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="io.github.hassannomani.phonecalling.OutgoingCallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

And finally the created ussd_service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged|typeWindowContentChanged"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:description="@string/app_desc"
android:notificationTimeout="0"
android:packageNames="io.github.hassannomani.phonecalling"
/>
```

Comment: Here's the link to the answer I tried and it didn't work in my case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34132708/3551312

Comment: You are right track. Now you need to capture the input sort of "edittext", write your choice (option), then click send button. 
All this is explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44480576/3427883