# reading ussd call responses IN flutter and use for later

Tags: flutter

i am currently trying to work on Unstructured Supplementary Service Data (USSD),  codes on flutter, i was able to dial 
Unstructured Supplementary Service Data (USSD), codes. but i don't know how to use the response inside the app.

Comment: What's your goal with that information? You want to store it? you want to show it inside your app? Could you provide more context and code examples of your work?

Comment: I guess the idea here is to read the information from the pop-up and close it automatically! Something in these lines but in flutter (not java/android) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793378/android-interacting-with-ussd-dialog-programmatically/44480576#44480576